# Corda - Unable to initialize main class Capsule (Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation)

Tags: java, corda

I'm trying to go through the Corda [Hello world example](https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-template.html) (specifically the Java version).
I got to the point where [nodes should be deployed](https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-running.html) but that fails:

```
> ./gradlew clean deployNodes                    

> Configure project :
Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0
        at build_9ngc7dap6wdyi5igmry41f6s9$_run_closure5.doCall(/home/foo/cordapp-template-java/build.gradle:85)
The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
        at build_9ngc7dap6wdyi5igmry41f6s9$_run_closure5.doCall(/home/foo/cordapp-template-java/build.gradle:85)

> Task :deployNodes
Bootstrapping local network in /home/foo/cordapp-template-java/build/nodes
Node config files found in the root directory - generating node directories
Generating directory for Notary
Generating directory for PartyA
Generating directory for PartyB
Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [PartyB, PartyA, Notary]
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
> Node in PartyB exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in /home/foo/cordapp-template-java/build/nodes/PartyB/logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
15 actionable tasks: 15 executed
```

I'm advised to see logs in `/home/foo/cordapp-template-java/build/nodes/PartyB/logs` which contains the file `node-info-gen.log` following contents:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class Capsule
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation
```

The same error is also in the PartyA and Notary logs.

**What might be the cause of this error?**

To make sure I didn't accidentally add changes that caused this I removed my changes and used the template project as-is:

```
> git status       
On branch release-V3
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/release-V3'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

> git branch -v                           
* release-V3 c9eed90 Reducing dependency on Jitpack by depending on new repository that is a combination of corda-releases and corda-dependencies (#37)
```

### My environment

```
> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

> lsb_release -a                                 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I also tried with Oracle JDK but had the exact same result.

```
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was some issue with my environment.
After reinstalling Java the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

while running the deployNodes ,  i think you should not run clean task.

```
1. ./gradlew clean build
2../gradlew deployNodes
```

It should work.

Comment: Unfortunatley this didn't make a difference in the outcome.